# How can we prevents a file/folder from being included in the codebase in Angular 12?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I have one scenario in which I need to import service files according environment variable. How can we achieve that ? Example is as bellow.

I have two folders with name of **dev** and **prod** in which I have service files with same name but different logic. I have one component in which I want to inject that service/dependency according to environment, means If I am creating prod build then service from **prod** folder should be added in bundle(bundle should not include **dev** folder services).

Please help me to achieve this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Like for environment.ts, you might be able to use https://angular.io/guide/build#configure-target-specific-file-replacements

```
"project": {
  "fileReplacements": [
    {
      "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
      "with": "src/environments/environment.project-b.ts"
    },
    {
      "replace": "src/app/services/dev/index.ts",
      "with": "src/app/services/prod/index.ts"
    }
  ]
}
```

index.ts in both dev and prod folder:

```
import { DbService } from './db.service'
import { ActionsDbService } from './actions.service'
import { ItemsDbService } from './items.service'

export {
  DbService,
  ActionsDbService,
  ItemsDbService
}
```

and in your other files which import for example ItemsDbService you would import from 'src/app/services/dev'

Comment: But this will not allow me to replace folder. Or may be I need to list out many files. I think that is not good option to list out many files in Angular.json file.

Comment: folderReplacements are not a thing, your only option here is to list out all files. In case you plan on creating loads of services this can be tedious, an alternative is to create an index.ts file in both your dev and prod folder which import all services, I will update my answer to demonstrate.